# Ph.D program let me transfer a course where I got a B-. Could the graduate school audit it out?

Tags: graduate-school, grading, transcript-of-records

My graduate program let me transfer a course where I got a B- during my Master's even though the policy is "B or higher." Should I bring this up before the final graduation audit by the Graduate School (not the department)?

The department told me I'm fine but I really want to make sure there's nothing potentially around the corner that could mess up my progress.

Answer (score 3):

Academic administrators are not infallible.

It's only a short email to someone who's job it is to answer those sorts of questions. And then you'll sleep better knowing you're OK.

Comment: Alrighty. The graduate office said they're reaching out to the Registrar's office and the Psychology department respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If the department said you are fine, then you are fine. It might depend on the meaning of "B or higher", which it could mean as "some kind of B or higher". If it would bring your GPA below B, however, you might go talk to the grad school. There is no harm it asking them in any case.

Sometimes decisions made can overrule such policies. If someone thought you were fine and so accepted the course, then it should be considered as accepted. Relax.

Your other questions here seem to indicate a lack of confidence, either in yourself or those around you. Maybe you should think about that, also. The school doesn't benefit by laying "traps" for graduate students.

Comment: The B- was worth a 2.7 in my previous graduate program. It may be the case that it's some form of a B or better for sure. I was told that transfer courses would not affect my current program's GPA though. I'll also reflect on your last part. My first Ph.D advisor was someone who laid "traps" and it's likely my PTSD from that experience (not hyperbole either since I'm clinically diagnosed) is talking when I make these posts.

Answer (score 1):

Azor's answer is very strong, but I've noodled over this question for awhile and for better or worse would like to offer a frame challenge.

While local conditions can vary, it is the responsibility of the faculty in your department to monitor your progress towards graduation and advise you correctly regarding graduation requirements. The student has a responsibility to read and understand documentation they've been presented on these topics by the Department.

If you have been in a PhD program for 4 years, you should have periodically received written or at least electronic documents from the department that indicate the dept's assessment of your progress towards graduation. These are all you should invest your energy into understanding, along with whatever formal requirements document the dept provides.

In my experience, students graduate who have passed exams, written a thesis which is approved by a committee, and have documentation that the dept believes they are on-track through their degree. This is all other formal requirements notwithstanding. If you've already received a job offer predicated on your graduating at a time you anticipated based on communications from the dept, it's even more likely that minor mismatches with the "paper" rules will be waived. It benefits exactly nobody to hold someone around to nitpick something like masters course transfer credits when their next opportunity is already available.

To conclude: It's not your responsibility to do the dept's job of tracking your progress for them. Make sure you have all documentation that effectively says: "This person's on track to graduate if they do X, Y, and Z." Let any audits run, you are only hurting yourself by preemptively admitting that you do not believe you fulfill requirements. Look out for yourself, not the university: You fulfill requirements if a reasonable person would think they do based on communications you have received. In the improbable event someone tries to nitpick you at the end over a transfer credit, try to get your department on-side with your docs. If necessary, escalate through to a dean and an ombuds with your documentation as evidence. Somebody will crack, these types of minor issues aren't worth anyone's time to enforce.

Comment: I see what you mean. You also likely saw my update but the course with the B- was officially dropped. They did clear the other matters with me at least. I'm going to stop asking at this point.